# How to bridge a wireless to a ethernet interface

Tags: wireless, network-bridge

I'm trying to get a wifi hotspot running on ubuntu and bridge it to the ethernet connection, so that the devices on the wifi appear on the same network, use the router's dhcp, and are able to access local devices on the local network.

I found some guides on setting up a bridge, but they seem to refer to connect an bridge the ethernet to the wireless so it can connect to an already established wifi, not use it as an access point itself.

Comment: There is a "Hotspot" button on modern Ubuntu.

Comment: Hotspot does not give me any control on the network settings. I need to be able to connect both ways into the local network.